# Problems with import stament when using tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, import

I have the following problem: I want to import a variable from one file into another. But when the file from which I import has a tkinter window, it opens the entire window instead of just importing the variable. How do I solve this ?

## Code from file1

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

A = "This is "
B = "a test."
C = A+B
D = Label(root, text=C, font="Arial 20 bold")
D.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

## Code from file2

```
from file1 import C
print(C)
```

Comment: Yes, this is what happens. What behaviour are you after?

Comment: I want it to only import the variable which I specified.

Comment: Yes, that happens as well.

Comment: @Sh23 sometimes the variable you are after can be dependant on the rest of the variables so python makes sure everything (including the window) is setup. I suggest that you move the window creating in a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because when you import python files, you are essentially running the entire file to get a reference. When file1 runs in its entirety, the entire file is interpreted and ran. This includes the last line, `root.mainloop()`

What you want to use is the best practice of having a check for if the current file is the main file. This will prevent it from running certain lines of code if it is not the current, main program.

You're looking for something like this:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: If OP does _just_ this, then the import will still cause the GUI to be created, it just won't be visible.